# Rebuilt Transmission on the Cadillac Escalade

Tags: cadillac, escalade

I  have installed a  Genuine GM Rebuild Transmission on the Cadillac, after installation is completed, the car can only drive in limp mode and check engine on.  Is some reprogramming required?

Comment: Probably. Have you read the codes?

Comment: If you have a code reader, check your codes and clear them.  If they come back, you have an issue that needs to be resolved.  If they don't, then they might have been thrown with the first start.  Have you ensured all your connections are connected and tight?